# What report is given to a boss at a higher rank by bypassing the immediate boss?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word that can be put before "report" meaning a report given to a boss at a higher rank by bypassing the immediate boss?

Comment: In the military, asking to confer with someone more than one level up the chain of command is known as "requesting mast"... I don't know that calling a similar report a "mast report" would be widely understood, if it's even used in military circles.

Comment: This is an interesting question. Looking at the answers below (and there are 6 at the time I'm writing this), some are invoking phases I've heard before; others are mentioning "well-understood" terminologies that I don't recall ever hearing.  My point?  There may not be a concise, universally-understood way to express this.  Therefore, even if you select some shortened terminology, you might want to parenthetically define what you mean, such as: _Fill out a skip-level report (which will go directly to the supervisor of the supervisor of the individual)._

Answer (score 3):

In some circles this type of report may be referred to as a ***skip-level*** report.

Comment: Skip-level is very common in the American business community, referring to one's immediate supervisor's boss.

Comment: Interesting. I've heard of "skip-level meetings", but always thought they referred to doing it the other way around: upper management wanting to talk directly to employees without mid-level management involved, i.e. top-down skipping rather than bottom-up skipping.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a single word to describe what you're asking, but the phrase "to go over someone's head" usually means to skip (at least) one rank in the hierarchy and address an issue to someone higher up.

Depending on how formal you're trying to be, perhaps you could use this to coin the phrase "an *over-the-head* report" - people should be able to figure out what it means, but as far as I'm aware it's not an existing word.

Answer (score 1):

Another colloquial phrase (from the military, I believe) is "jumping the chain of command," in case you can use a phrase instead of a single word.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of the context here. If you feel that this was the wrong thing for the person to do, you could say it was *subversive* report. That is, if you think it was given to the superior for the purpose of subverting an established chain of command.

Answer (score 0):

You might also refer to it (figuratively and imprecisely) as an *[out-of-band](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-band_signaling)* report, or as a *[back-channel](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/backchannel#English)* report, in the sense "An unofficial communications channel used to make informal or subversive negotiations". Or, using a word from your question, as a *[bypass](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bypass)* report or an *[end-around](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-around)* report.

Answer (score 0):

A generic name, well-worn and understood, is "direct report".

"He submitted a direct report to the manager in case of a major client and regular reports to his supervisor".

This has no negative connotations, does not refer to superceding the immediate superior as such, but conveys the simple fact. Yet by implication, all these constructions can be made, depending on the reader. It is as if it is up to the reader to draw his own interpretations.